# Java CAS operation performs faster than C equivalent, why?

Tags: java, c, concurrency, compare-and-swap

- Here I have Java and C code that tries to do an Atomic increment operation using CAS.
- To increment an long variable from 0 to 500,000,000.
- C : Time taken : 7300ms
- Java : Time Taken : 2083ms
- Can any one double check these results? Because I just can't believe them.
- Thanks

Java code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class SmallerCASTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final long MAX = 500l * 1000l * 1000l;
        final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        while (true) {
            if (counter.incrementAndGet() >= MAX) {
                break;
            }
        }

        long casTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start);
        System.out.println("Time Taken=" + casTime + "ms");
    }

}
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NITER 500000000


int main (){
   long val = 0;     
   clock_t starttime = clock ();
    while (val < NITER){
      while (1){
        long current = val;
        long next = current+1;
        if ( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (&val, current, next))
            break;
      }
     } 
   clock_t castime = (clock()-starttime)/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
   printf ("Time taken : %d ",castime);
}
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -O3 test.c -o test.o
echo -e "\nC"
./test.o
javac SmallerCASTest.java
echo -e "\nJava"
java SmallerCASTest
```

Other details:

```
System : Linux XXXXXXXXX #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 08:00:08 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version:
 gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

java -version: 
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You could get better results in Java by warming up the JVM before measuring. And it is conceivable that because your code is single threaded, the JVM optimises the need for synchronization away, effectively incrementing a long variable. It might even determine that the incremented variable is never used, and optimise the whole loop away... etc...

Comment: can someone reproduce the number for the java example? on my machine the java example takes 7500ms

Comment: On my machine (Xeon X3450), the java version takes ~4700 ms, the C version ~4600 ms, a C version using __sync_add_and_fetch() ~3800 ms.

Comment: @janneb, by any chance are you using mac? what os, version of java and c, also you using openJDK or sunJDK. I have found that on mac both programs perform the same. Also results are different with OpenJDK. I am specifically interested in sunJdk, on linux it tends to outperform C.

Comment: @Jigar: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing apples with oranges as I am sure you expected. The `java` version is a true CAS with retry on failure while the `C` version is using what I'd call in `java` a `synchronized` form.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12498483/823393) for more details.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498665/823393) to that question for supporting narrative where it says `A full memory barrier is created when this function is invoked`, i.e. in java terms, this is a `synchronized` call.

Try using [_compare_and_swap](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v121v141/topic/com.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc/compiler_ref/bif_compare_and_swap_compare_and_swaplp.html) in the same way `AtomicLong` uses its java equivalent, i.e. spin on the function until the value changes to what you want it to be.

**Added:**

I cannot find a definitive C++ equivalent of a java `AtomicLong` but that does not mean there isn't one. Essentially, an `AtomicLong` can be changed by any thread at any time and just one of them succeeds. However, the change will be consistent, i.e. the change will be the result of the change by one or other of the threads, it will not be a combination of the two. If thread A attempts to change the value to 0xffff0000 (or the equivalent 64bit number) while thread B attempts a change to 0x0000ffff (ditto) the result will be **either** of the two values, more specifically it will **not** be 0x00000000 or 0xffffffff (unless of course a third thread gets involved).

Essentially, an `AtomicLong` has **no synchronisation at all** other than this.

Comment: As I understand, are you trying to say that the  __sync_** is creating a memory barrier, and compiler is unable to optimize code around it, hence the slowdown?

If so, is there some alternative in GCC, that I could use achieve equivalent results as java? (the _compare_and_swap link you provided is pointing to some "XL C for AIX, V12.1" compiler, which I don't think I can use.)

Comment: Not a C++ guru - sorry. I don't know of an equivalent, perhaps someone else will suggest one.

Comment: ... but [this](http://golubenco.org/2007/06/14/atomic-operations/) may be a good start. It looks like just using a `volatile` may be an effective equivalent. Actually - don't go there, just use a `volatile`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon *"just use a volatile"* -- no, not for C or C++. semantics/guarantees in Java vs C or C++ are different. don't go *there* :)

Comment: @justin - thanks for the heads-up - I'm not a c++ guru at all. It seems that the concept of `atomic` means totally different things in C++ and java. In java it means "not synchronized at all so expect it to change in very weird ways", what does it generally mean in c++.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon C++ (and C) execute using sequential consistency. e.g. the compiler and/or the hardware are free to reorder instructions so long as they happen "as-if" they were not reordered. accesses and reads/writes to memory are by default unfettered, may be reordered, interrupted, etc. the exact implementation of an atomic operation varies by architecture. atomicity under the latest C++ and C memory models is in effect a guarantee that an atomic operation on a memory region cannot be interrupted (e.g. context switch) or that the region may not accessed from another thread at the same time.

Comment: A Java atomic CAS also establishes a "full memory barrier", it has the same effect of syncronized{} in memory model.

Comment: @irreputable ... "it has the same effect of syncronized{}" ... except that it will never block or be blocked.

Comment: as far as Java memory model is concerned, CAS is like a lock-unlock pair.

Comment: Nonsense!! CAS **does not lock/block at all EVER**!!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : I decompiled the above c code (http://pastebin.com/4nnNX9Re), and as janneb pointed in another comment, "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap" gets converted to "lock cmpxchgq". Are you trying to say there is something better that Java does, which is TRUE CAS? because you have not given any reference, substantiating your claim. Hence, I am down-voting your answer.

Comment: @Jigar - My discussion of the `AtomicLong` class describes what I believe would be termed a true CAS, i.e. there is no lock other than to ensure that the changes do not blend. If that is insufficient argument, by all means downvote. My point is that java does not lock while C does, thus the speedup.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Sorry but things are not clear, your use of word lock is ambiguous.  "lock cmpxchgq" instruction (decomplied from C code) is the best instruction that I know of to do CAS, how can java native code produce anything better than this is beyond me. Regardless, the "lock" prefix in this case, does exactly what you describe/hope the java version does. (ref- http://goo.gl/zMHb8) And your claim that the C version does something similar to java's synchronized is completely false (As seen from the decompiled C code.) Hence the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Indeed, java seems to implement incrementAndGet using a CAS operation, as you point out.

My testing seems to suggest that the C and Java versions have roughly equivalent performance (which makes sense, as the time consuming part is the atomic rather than any optimization of the rest that the java or C compilers manage to do).

So on my machine (Xeon X3450), the java version takes ~4700 ms, the C version ~4600 ms, a C version using __sync_add_and_fetch() ~3800 ms (suggesting that java could be improved here instead of implementing all the atomic operations on top of CAS).

java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

GCC is 4.4.3, x86_64.

OS is Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64.

So I can only conclude that something seems fishy in your tests.

Comment: Don't think so, check the source of incrementAndGet. http://pastebin.com/Cu8Q7aVy

Comment: Nopes, nothing's proven fishy yet. As you said, you are using OpenJDK, try sunJDK, then we can talk about my tests being fishy. Regardless, thanks for running these tests, I'll remove my downvote now.

Comment: @Jigar: Well, I do think it's quite fishy if sunjdk  can do "lock cmpxchg" a factor of 3 times faster than C or openjdk. It would be interesting to see the asm generated (is that possible in java somehow?).

Answer (score 0):

Because Java is awesome?

The java version takes 4ns for each loop. That is about right. An uncontended CAS is actually a CPU local operation, it should be very fast. (edit: probably not 4ns fast!)

Java achieves that speed by aggressive runtime optimization, the code is inlined and becomes just a couple of machine instructions, i.e. as fast as one can hand-code in assembly.

If the gcc version couldn't inline the function call, that's a big overhead per loop.

Comment: There's no function call in the GCC version, __sync_bool_compare_and_swap is a compiler builtin which on x86_64 is expanded into "lock cmpxchgq".

Comment: then there shouldn't be much difference. I just ran OP's java example and it takes 7500ms on my machine. I don't believe OP's machine can be that faster than mine, so he probably screwed up his test numbers.

Comment: I can assure you that I have not screwed up any numbers. I have ran these types of tests multiple times, with more than one-pair of eyes to review. I was running these tests, with multiple threads, and multiple counters. We were shocked with the results, hence we wrote a minimal test that highlights my discovery. Also we are using amazon's EC2 standard-medium instance to run these tests. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ .Results differ with, mac and openJDK. But I am interested only in SunJdk on linux.

Comment: @Jigar ask experts: http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/mailman/listinfo/concurrency-interest